# How is OnParametersSetAsync executed and the number of executions

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

If there are two parameter changes in the blazer server, will OnParametersSetAsync be executed once after each change or will OnParametersSetAsync be executed once after both changes are executed. Why does OnParametersSetAsync execute twice when the homepage is first loaded

I think the lifecycle of a blazer is a bit chaotic, such as the uncertain number of OnParametersSetAsync executions, OnInitialized executions twice and resetting the second time, and OnAfterRender sometimes without a true parameter. In short, it's very chaotic and frustrating

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If there are two parameter changes in the blazer server, will `OnParametersSetAsync` be executed once after each change or will `OnParametersSetAsync` be executed once after both changes are executed?

Setting parameter values in a component once it has rendered will not trigger `OnParametersSetAsync` on a child component.

That will only happen when the parent component renders either as the result of a UI event handler call or you  manually calling `StateHasChanged`.  `StateHasChanged` queues a render request onto the Renderer's queue in the form of a `RenderFragment`.  The Renderer executes this `RenderFragment` and checks if the parameters for any sub-components have changed.  It calls `SetParametersAsync` on any components where the parameters may have changed.

> I think the lifecycle of a blazer is a bit chaotic

That's because you don't current have the necessary knowledge to fully understand it.
It's not a simple subject: you won't master components in a day!  I was once where you are today, so I understand your fustrations.

Answer (score 2):

The flow is pretty clear:

[image]

OnParametersSet will execute once per render cycle, independent of the number of parameters. Including zero parameters.

You see it happening twice on Blazor Server because of `RenderMode="ServerPrerendered"`

Switch to ServerRendered if you don't want prerendering.